# What is the Australian Calculator?

Tags: sample, population

i need to know how to use the Australian Calculator to get my sample size. i was instructed to carry out my research using the Australian Calculator, but i don't know what it means.

Comment: What exactly is this Australian calculator meant to do? Personally I've never heard of it. Being more specific about the problem and this method might help to attract potential answers.

Comment: What are you trying to *do*?

Answer (score 1):

I assume "Australian Calculator" refers to [this page - Sample Size Calculator](http://www.nss.gov.au/nss/home.nsf/pages/Sample+size+calculator) , which is owned by Australian National Statistics Service and contains a sample size calculator.

Comment: Aurelian - google search results are tailored these days, which means I may get different results from you with the same search terms

Comment: Right. I missed that. I will correct the answer.